# In Pinax, how to invite when ACCOUNT_OPEN_SIGNUP = False?

Tags: python, django, pinax, invite, invitation

In Pinax, when

```
ACCOUNT_OPEN_SIGNUP = False
```

how does the admin invite more users to the system?

How does one generate invitation codes? How do they work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way currently is to hit `/admin/invite_user/` as a site admin. Currently, you can only send out one invitation at a time. We are definitely going to improve this in 0.9. Suggestions welcome.